# Doesn't run RunOnUiThread after running some Task with ContinueWith or delegate

Tags: c#, delegates, xamarin.android, async-await, task-parallel-library

I want to change my UI elements(hide progressbar and assign data for listview) in UI-thread after running Task(obtaining some data from API). Problem with API I haven't find, data returning in all cases. Sometimes executing of code(in  RunOnUiThread)after running Task becomes unreponsive, especially when I run code in Debug mode without any breakpoints. When I catch breakpoint before calling Task and continue running, all works fine.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            _userData = ServiceLocator.GetService<IAuthService>().GetUserData();
            _wallsViewPresenter = ViewPresenterHelper.CreateViewPresenter<WallViewPresenter, IWallView, WallActivity>(this);
            _listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.postList);

            progressBar = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar1);
            Task.Run(async () => {
                profile = await _wallsViewPresenter.GetProfile(int.Parse(_userData.Profile));
                WallModel wall = SerializationService.DeSerialize<WallModel>(profile.Wall);
                _posts = (List<PostModel>) (wall.Posts.ToList());                        
            }).ContinueWith(ar =>
            {
                RunOnUiThread(() => {
                    progressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                    _postListAdapter = new PostListAdapter(this, _posts);
                    _listView.Adapter = _postListAdapter;
                    SetListViewHeader();
                    _listView.AddHeaderView(_header);
                    FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.details).Text = profile.Name;
                });
            });               
        }
```

Version with delegate:

```
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        _userData = ServiceLocator.GetService<IAuthService>().GetUserData();
        _wallsViewPresenter = ViewPresenterHelper.CreateViewPresenter<WallViewPresenter, IWallView, WallActivity>(this);
        _listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.postList);
        progressBar = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar1);
        Task.Run(async () => {
            profile = await _wallsViewPresenter.GetProfile(int.Parse(_userData.Profile));
            WallModel wall = SerializationService.DeSerialize<WallModel>(profile.Wall);
            _posts = (List<PostModel>) (wall.Posts.ToList());
            if (_posts.Count != 0)
            {
                DataPopulated?.Invoke(this, true);
            }
        });
        DataPopulated += (sender, e) => {
            RunOnUiThread(() => {
                progressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                _postListAdapter = new PostListAdapter(this, _posts);
                _listView.Adapter = _postListAdapter;
                SetListViewHeader();
                _listView.AddHeaderView(_header);
                FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.details).Text = profile.Name;
            });
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ContinueWith` is a very dangerous, low-level API; and should not be used here. Also, with `async`/`await`, there's no need for `RunOnUIThread`.

It's also likely that the `Task.Run` is unnecessary, since the method you're calling is already asynchronous.

Simplified version:

```
protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
  _userData = ServiceLocator.GetService<IAuthService>().GetUserData();
  _wallsViewPresenter = ViewPresenterHelper.CreateViewPresenter<WallViewPresenter, IWallView, WallActivity>(this);
  _listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.postList);

  progressBar = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar1);
  profile = await _wallsViewPresenter.GetProfile(int.Parse(_userData.Profile));
  WallModel wall = SerializationService.DeSerialize<WallModel>(profile.Wall);
  _posts = (List<PostModel>) (wall.Posts.ToList());                        

  progressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
  _postListAdapter = new PostListAdapter(this, _posts);
  _listView.Adapter = _postListAdapter;
  SetListViewHeader();
  _listView.AddHeaderView(_header);
  FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.details).Text = profile.Name;
}
```

Comment: thanks but after calling method `profile = await _wallsViewPresenter.GetProfile(int.Parse(_userData.Profile));` code becomes unresponsive and progressbar continue works(not hided)

Comment: @IgorLevkivskiy: Sounds like your "asynchronous" method is actually synchronous. In that case, a quick fix is to wrap the middle 4 lines of code inside an `await Task.Run(() => {` ... `});`.